# jQuery .filter() method doesn't return elements as expected in jQuery 1.5.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-filter

The names of some of my HTML inputs contain multiple square brackets.

E.g.

```
<input name="skus[0].skuattributeoptions[1].sao_option_id" value="559" />
```

I have read that you can have attribute values with square brackets so long as you enclose the value in quotes. Which is fine but, when I use .filter() on a jquery object that contains elements with a name like the above, no elements are returned.

Below is a screenshot of the output from Chrome's console that illustrates what I mean.

`inputs = $('[name="skus[0].skuattributeoptions[1].sao_option_id"]')`
returns three elements as expected.

But when I use `inputs.filter('[name="skus[0].skuattributeoptions[1].sao_option_id"]')` on that same bunch of elements I get nothing returned.

Please note that when the selector passed into .filter() has only one set of square brackets, E.g. `inputs.filter('[name*="skuattributeoptions[1].sao_option_id"]')` the filter returns what I expected!

I am using jQuery 1.5.1. Am I doing something wrong?

http://www.photogifts.co.uk/content/images/affiliate/example/jquery-filter-issue.png

Comment: This works for me as expected, not using jQuery 1.5.1 though, http://jsfiddle.net/fjeCX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, I just tried it using jQuery 1.5.1 and it returned an empty set `[]`, I would recommend updating the jQuery, if you have to use it, you can read the `name` properties instead:

```
inputs.filter(function() {
   return this.name === "skus[0].skuattributeoptions[1].sao_option_id";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zVUNm/

**Edit**: And it also work if you escape the `[`, `]` and `.` characters instead of using quotes, it seems there is a bug in jQuery 1.5.1's `.filter()` method:

```
inputs.filter('[name=skus\\[0\\]\\.skuattributeoptions\\[1\\]\\.sao_option_id]');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tE4et/

Well, that version is an old one, it had been released in February of 2011 and this problem doesn't exist in newer versions.

Comment: Great answer. I had tried escaping only [], didn't realise it also needed the dots escaping too.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.5.1 is very outdated While the last features added to [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) were in jQuery 1.4 (filter by selector in 1.0), there have been fixes since. Your problems seem to be between jQuery 1.5.1 and IE. You should use jQuery 1.10.1 instead.